# What is the role of HS level sstatus.MXR in two stage paging when hgatp.MODE=BARE?

Tags: paging, riscv, hypervisor

Note: The document version used for the quote below is 20211203 dated October 2, 2023.

In section 9.5 of the RISCV privileged spec there is the following statement:

```
The vsstatus field MXR, which makes execute-only pages readable, only overrides VS-stage page protection. Setting MXR at VS-level does not override guest-physical page protections. Setting MXR at HS-level, however, overrides both VS-stage and G-stage execute-only permissions.
```

If the following are true:

- Machine is operating in VS mode
- HS level MXR = 1
- VS level MXR = 0
- VSATP.MODE != BARE
- HGATP.MODE  = BARE

Does the HS level MXR still override the VS level execute pages as readable when the HGATP mode is bare?

Thank you.

If the spec is followed to the letter, it appears that HS level MXR would indeed make the Execute only pages readable independent of hgatp.mode. It seems odd that hgatp.MODE=BARE(which seems to be the only way to disable two stage paging when V=1) would allow the VS stage execute permissions to be overidden.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the HS level MXR still override the VS level execute pages as
> readable when the HGATP mode is bare?

Yes it would AFAIU. The `sstatus.MXR` will be ignored for G-stage translations as the translation stage is disabled, but for VS-stage translation it would make executable readable.

`sstatus.MXR` is supposed to be used in hypervisor handlers when reading guest instructions as part of a trap and it is supposed to be 0 otherwise.

If let's say `sstatus.MXR` doesn't effect the VS-mapping when `hgatp`=BARE, then to read the guest instruction, hypervisor will need to rely on updating `vsstatus.MXR` and it will create multiple paths of trap handling depending when `hgatp` is BARE or not.

What I mean is, in trap handler, hypervisor will have to set `sstatus.MXR`=1 when `hgatp` != BARE to read guest instructions and when `hgatp` == BARE, it will have to set `vsstatus.MXR`=1 to access guest instruction.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. I am still unclear why the handler could not just use `hlv/hlvx` instructions   to accomplish this when hgatp.MODE=BARE.

Comment: Ironically I didn't notice this even though I have used these quite much. This is purely based on assumption from browsing through spec commits and issues. Looking at https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/commit/17d51cde8936cc17c05b120a385ee19115dd4933#diff-1078b525ce14ede79911112609ab0edd4db2565eb50a3ac59f1951a8f2d5acc8R1683 I can see hlvx was added after MXR and MXR behaviour is defined for hlv instructions. I am assuming we have two ways of doing the same thing. HLVX one being the better one as pointed here https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual/issues/682#issuecomment-884562649.

Comment: I am assuming that MXR was added to S-mode and with hypervisor extension it was extended to VS/VU modes but with HLVX instructions present I am not able to think of any use-case where MXR is useful and HLVX can't be used.